# SQL Server : how to divide database records into even, random groups

Tags: sql-server, random

**tblNames**

- OrganizationID (int)
- LastName (varchar)
- ...
- GroupNumber (int)

`GroupNumber` is currently NULL for all records, I need an `UPDATE` statement to update this column.

I need to split up records on an `OrganizationID` level into even, random groups.

If there are < 20,000 records for an `OrganizationID`, I need 2 even, random groups. So records for that `OrganizationID` will have a `GroupNumber` of 1 or 2. There will be the same (or if odd number of records difference of only 1) number of records for `GroupNumber = 1` and for `GroupNumber = 2`, and there will be no recognizable way to tell how a person got into a GroupNumber - i.e. LastNames that start with A-L are group 1, M-Z are group 2 would not be OK.

If there are > 20,000 records for an `OrganizationID`, I need 4 even, random groups. So records for that `OrganizationID` will have a `GroupNumber` values of 1, 2, 3, or 4. There will be the same (or if odd number of records difference of only 1) number of records for each `GroupNumber`, and there will be no recognizable way to tell how a person got into a GroupNumber - i.e. LastNames that start with A-F are group 1, G-L are group 2, etc. would not be OK.

There are only about 20 organizations, so I can run an update statement 20 times, once per `organizationID` if needed.

I have full control of the table so I can add keys or columns, but for now this is what it is.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Outsider to MSSQL, but Can't you grab the IDs, shuffle them in the language of your choice, and make n update queries for portions of the resulting array where n is the group count?

Comment: I can't even read your question

Answer (score 1):

Create row numbers randomly (with `ROW_NUMBER` and `GETID`). Then get their modulo 2 or 4 depending on the record count to get buckets 0 to 1 or 0 to 3.

```
select 
  organizationid, lastname, ...,
  case when cnt <= 20000 then rn % 2 else rn % 4 end as bucket
from
(
  select 
    organizationid, lastname, ...,
    row_number() over(order by newid()) as rn,
    count(*) over () as cnt
  from mytable
) randomized;
```

**UPDATE:** I suppose the update statement would have to look something like this:

```
with randomized as
(
  select 
    groupnumber,
    row_number() over(order by newid()) as rn,
    count(*) over () as cnt
  from mytable
)
update randomzized
set groupnumber = case when cnt <= 20000 then rn % 2 else rn % 4 end + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly different approach;

Setting up some fake data:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Orgs') is not null drop table #Orgs
create table #Orgs
(
    RID int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
    OrganizationId int,
    LastName varchar(36),
    GroupId int
)

insert into #Orgs (OrganizationId, LastName)
select top 40000 row_number() over (order by (select null)) % 20000, newid()
from sys.all_objects a, sys.all_objects b
```

then using the rarely useful `ntile()` function to get as close to identically sized groups as possible. Sorting by `newid()` essentially sorts the data randomly (or as random as generating one guid to the next is).

```
declare @NumRandomGroups int = 4

update o
set GroupId = x.GroupId 
from #orgs o 
inner join (select RID, GroupId = ntile(@NumRandomGroups) over (order by newid())
            from #orgs) x 
    on o.RID = x.RID

select GroupId, count(1)
from #Orgs
group by GroupId

select *
from #Orgs
order by RID
```

You can then set `@NumRandomGroups` to whatever you want it to be based on the count of Organizations

Comment: `ntile`! *That's* what I was trying to remember when I read this earlier :)